# The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.11' failed

Tags: mysql

I have tried installing MySQL 8.0.11 community version many times but every time server installation fails and all the other services are installed. Please tell me how can I install it properly?

Here is some of its log:

```
Size: 266875
1: Action 14:50:55: RunPostInstall. 
1: Action 14:50:55: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: rpxm3ds_|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: 7ejegqmo|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 14:50:55: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Location, Value: 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Version, Value: 8.0.11
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: DataLocation, Value: 
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, 
Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, 
Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 14:50:56: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 14:50:56: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: RunPostInstall
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {11CF35A6-DF56-426A-8FEF-BAA039D8FF31} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.11' failed.
```

Thank You.